# Difference between function instance, function object and function output in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I couldn't figure out what should be the output of this.

Can someone please explain?

```js
const a = new RandomFunc('test');
const b = RandomFunc;
const c = RandomFunc('test');

function RandomFunc(val) {
  this.newKey = val;
}

console.log(a.newKey)
console.log(b.newKey);
console.log(c.newKey);
```

Comment: So I made a snippet. Now you know

Comment: https://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html and https://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html might help

Comment: this might be help https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp

Answer (score 0):

`a.newKey` is `test`, as you've created a `RandomFunc` object using the `new` keyword with `new RandomFunc('test');`. This makes `a` an instance of `RandomFunc` with an attribute `newKey` correctly set to `test`, as the function was called when you instantiated it with `new`.  In Javascript, everything is an object, including functions.

`b.newKey` is `undefined`, as you provided `b` with the **function object** that represents the function `RandomFunc` ; it tries to access its attribute `newKey`, but it has none as functions do not have an attribute `newKey` in JS, obviously.

`c.newKey` throws a TypeError exception as `c` is undefined : it's equal to the output of the function `RandomFunc`. However, it has no return value, so it returns `undefined`.